# Ionic / AngularJS $injector error ONLY in android emulator

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-injector

This is returning an error `Undefined is not a function` at `if(url.includes('api')` but if I look at console, `config.url` absolutely has `url` defined even before the first error is displayed in console.

```
.factory('authInterceptor', ['$q', '$injector', function($q, $injector,tokenUrl){
    var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};
    var $http;

var _request = function(config) {
    var url = config.url;
    if (url.includes('api')) {
        //only send token to requests to api
        var access_token = 'abc223blahblahblah';
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + access_token;
    }
    return config;
};
```

What gives? These errors are only generated when emulating the Ionic project in  android....NOT in ios or the browser.

Comment: Solved by using `indexOf()` instead of `.includes()` .  Anyone know why this would be the case ONLY on Android platform?

Comment: [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is an ECMAScript 6 method and may not be available on all JavaScript implementations yet. Or, perhaps you tested this on an older version of Android?